# How do I prevent going backwards in an opportunity once a specific step is reached?

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, opportunity, stagename

I need to prevent users to change opportunity status back to an earlier stage once a specific stage has been reached.

StageName values in order are:

- New
- Preselection
- Instruct
- Closed (Won/Lost)

Once an opportunity has been marked "Instruct", users should not be allowed to go backwards.

I have tried the following validation rule, I get no error but it doesn't work:

```
AND(
  OR(
   PRIORVALUE( StageName )= "Instruct",
   PRIORVALUE( StageName )= "Closed won",
   PRIORVALUE( StageName )= "Closed lost"
  ),
 OR(
  ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Preselection"),
  ISPICKVAL( StageName , "New")
 )    
)
```

Can you help me out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the CASE statement. We'll convert each option to a numerical value, and generate an error if the step is lower than the previous step.

```
CASE(
  StageName, 
  'New', 1, 
  'Preselection', 1, 
  'Instruct', 2, 
  'Closed Won', 3, 
  'Closed Lost', 3, 
  0 
) 
<
CASE(
  PRIORVALUE(StageName), 
  'New', 1, 
  'Preselection', 1, 
  'Instruct', 2, 
  'Closed Won', 3, 
  'Closed Lost', 3, 
  0 
)
```

You can assign the numbers however you want, this is just an example.